# ¿Como puedo cambiar APache 2 y Mysql a modo automático en Linux MInt?

Tags: php, linux-mint

estoy creando un ambiente local en mi laptop , recién le instalé LInuxMInt.

No instalé XAMPP porque necesito hacer algunas configuraciones avanzadas en mis hosts de apache2 y hacer eso con XAMPP es un dolor de cabeza.

Instalé todo aparte php 7.4, mysql y apache2, el tema esque quiero que el servicio de apache2 y mysql no inicien de forma automático, sino cuando yo los encienda con un systemctl start apache2 por ejemplo. Porque no quiero que me consuman ram si no estoy trabajando con algún proyecto de php.

Gracias!

Comment: Prueba con `systemctl disable httpd.service`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el comando `systemctl disable` se deshabilita el inicio automático de servicios.

```
# systemctl disable apache2.service
# systemctl disable mariadb.service
```